# How to extract multiple zip files with possible duplicate file names in a single folder

Tags: windows, script, zip, extract

I have a list of many zip files(with duplicate names) that need to be downloaded(maybe by wget) each of them contain a single file , I need to extract all of them into a single directory , but due to duplicate names there are conflicts which need to be resolved by appending file size as a unique identifier for the file followed by a number if there is size conflicts.

Note: I use windows 8 , but also have bash shell on it.

So which command can solve this?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Ramhound windows

Comment: Update your question to reflect that don't just use tags.  What program are you using to extract the zip file?  Indicate what version of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I use windows 8 , but also have bash shell